# React Native: Is there any way to check if the file exists in android_asset folder or not?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I need to check file existence in the folder like this:

```
file:///android_asset/contents/my.html
```

I've tried to use react-native-filesystem plugin

```
componentWillMount () {
    async function checkIfFileExists() {
      const fileExists = await FileSystem.fileExists('file:///android_asset/contents/my.html')
      console.log(`file exists: ${fileExists}`)
    }
}
```

I'm sure that my.html file is there, but I get false in fileExists.
Does anybody know how to check it properly?

Comment: i think react native has nothing to do with this. what you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `react-native-fs`.

Looks like they have a function to just what you're looking for: https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs#existsassetsfilepath-string-promiseboolean

Answer (score 0):

using RNFS you can check file exist or not

Here is the Example

```js
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';

const filePath = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/example.txt';

RNFS.exists(filePath)
  .then((exists) => {
    if (exists) {
      console.log('File exists');
    } else {
      console.log('File does not exist');
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

https://medium.com/@romik-mk/how-to-check-file-exist-in-react-native-df8195baea3